# Using a C++11 Range for loop to Change the Characters in a string

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, reference

I read in [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) :

> If we want to change the value of the characters in a string, we must define the
>   loop variable as a reference type (§ 2.3.1, p. 50). Remember that a
>   reference is just another name for a given object. **When we use a
>   reference as our control variable, that variable is bound to each
>   element in the sequence in turn.** Using the reference, we can change
>   the character to which the reference is bound.

Further they give this code :

```
string s("Hello World!!!");
// convert s to uppercase
for (auto &c : s)   // for every char in s (note: c is a reference)
    c = toupper(c); // c is a reference, so the assignment changes the char
in s
cout << s << endl;
```

> The output of this code is HELLO WORLD!!!

I also read :

> **There is no way to rebind a reference to refer to a different object**.
>   Because there is no way to rebind a reference, references must be
>   initialized.

Question : Won't this code cause rebinding each time the reference variable `c` is binded to next character of string s ?

```
for (auto &c : s)   
    c = toupper(c);
```

Comment: `c` is not rebound, but the variable it's pointing to is reassigned. If `c` would be a pointer the code would be `*c = toupper(*c);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no rebinding of an existing variable, at each iteration the "old" c dies and the "new" c is created again, initialized to the next character. That `for` loop is equivalent to:

```
{
    auto it = begin(s);
    auto e = end(s);
    // until C++17: auto it = begin(s), e = end(s);
    for(; it!=e; ++it) {
        auto &c = *it;
        c=toupper((unsigned char)c);
    }
}
```

where you see that, at each iteration, `c` is re-created and re-initialized.

In other words, a variable declared inside the round parentheses of a range-based `for` loop has the body of the loop as its scope.

Comment: @Mattteo I do understand that `body of the loop is its scope`, but can you please point to the part where it is specified that each time the loop runs, variable specified gets destroyed and new one is created ?

Comment: In the C++ standard, it's at §6.5.4 ¶1; the *for-range-declaration* is put inside the body of the "regular" `for` loop; then, the fact that the variable is created/destroyed at each iteration follows from §6.5 ¶2, where it says "The substatement in an iteration-statement implicitly defines a block scope (3.3) which is entered and exited each time through the loop.".

Answer (score 5):

**No.** A new reference is initialized for each iteration in the `for` loop.

```
for (auto &c : s)   
    c = toupper(c);
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
{
    auto &c = *it;
    c = toupper(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
char s[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};

for (int secret_index=0; secret_index<5; ++secret_index) {
    char &c = s[secret_index];
    c = toupper(c);
}
```

A new reference (with the same variable name) is initialized on every iteration. That is, the for loop enters *and leaves* the scope on every iteration.